# Any Appender for elasticsearch available for log4php to avoid logstash

Tags: php, elasticsearch, appender, elasticsearch-plugin, log4php

I need to log my messages to elasticsearch. In .net there is elasticsearch appender available for log4net [ https://github.com/jptoto/log4net.ElasticSearch ]. Any Idea of elasticsearch appender available for log4php.

Comment: Looking for one myself. Monolog (https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) has one, maybe one could port the app to use monolog or port the monolog formatter  to log4php and use it with LoggerAppenderSocket.